# How to screen record only one workspace or selected workspaces in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, desktop-recording

Is there any software to record only one or multiple [workspaces](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html.en)  in Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to make a tutorial video and I want only one workspace to record and not the other one.

And please note, I'm not asking about recording any particular **Area** or **Window** or **Screen**, I'm talking about a particular **[Workspace](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html.en)** in Ubuntu. 
Here is a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/2OTwHSa1KVc?t=31) showing **Workspace** in Ubuntu.

Comment: have you tried with any particular recorder or not yet?

Comment: screen recorders record the Display, either in full or part of. They don't have any concept of workspaces. So while recording don't go to another workspace..

Comment: @PRATAP, I've tried 2-3 popular open source screen recorder (i.e. Kazam, SimpleScreenRecorder)  but none of them have an option to record only particular workspace.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@doug](https://askubuntu.com/users/27773/doug) in [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104890/how-to-screen-record-only-one-workspace-or-selected-workspaces-in-ubuntu-18-04#comment1822176_1104890), screen recording softwares are usually workspace-agnostic in the sense that they don't have any concept of workspaces and record whatever is currently on your screen(s) or monitor(s) (either the full display or an allocated area or window).

So if you want to record only one workspace, just *do not switch* to other workspaces while recording. The [video](https://youtu.be/2OTwHSa1KVc?t=31) you added to your question also shows the same behaviour.